# Install downloaded package via tlmgr

Tags: packages, installing, texlive

I’d like to install a package (microtype 2.5 beta 4) under TeX Live that isn’t available in the official repository.

Now, I know that it’s usually enough to put the package under `~/texmf/tex/latex/` but I was wondering if I couldn’t use `tlmgr` to do the grunt work for me.

In particular, I noticed that `tlmgr` has a `--repository` option that can be used to pass it a local repository path. However, the following command unfortunately fails (understandably, since there is no TeX Live database file `texlive.tlpdb` there to read from):

```
wget http://xetex.tk/mediawiki/images/1/1c/Microtype.tds.zip
unzip Microtype.tds.zip
tlmgr --repository=./Microtype.tds/ update microtype
```

I was wondering if there was still a possibility to make this work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

why do you need tlmgr here. unzip the tds into your local tree:

```
unzip -d `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL'` Microtype.tds.zip
```

the TeXLive manager needs a repository with some more information.

Comment: Why I need it here: I was actually hoping that I could install the beta version of the microtype package alongside the old version in my local repository. Having tested your way, I see that this apparently isn’t necessary at all. I’ll accept your answer but I’ll probably delete the question since it doesn’t make sense in hindsight.

Comment: no, it is a question of what tlmgr can do and can not do ...

Comment: @Herbert: `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL` is more portable (`kpseexpand` doesn't exist on windows AFAIK).

Comment: @Konrad: I agree with Herbert, the question is legitimate, even if the answer is that tlmgr can't.

Comment: ok, I made it windows friendly

Comment: @Herbert: I'm afraid you left an extra quote `'` after `TEXMFLOCAL`.

Comment: OK, so I did this for `unzip -d `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL` titlepic.zip`, but when I do `texdoc titlepic` after this, nothing is shown; did also `texhash`, no `texdoc titlepic` either. So what command do I need to run after this unzip, so the package is actually seen by latex?

Comment: Did you forget to mention `texhash`?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I add manually a new package (ex: xyz) on Linux Fedora:

`sudo dnf install 'tex(xyz.sty)'`.

For the Debian-based distros it should be something like (I've not tried):

`sudo apt-get install 'tex(xyz.sty)'`.

This puts the package under the system-wide home for Tex packages and not user based one. For Fedora it is:

`/etc/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/`.

Comment: I think this packaging is specific to Fedora (and not even currently found on other Red Hat-related distros).  It also won't provide anything that wasn't packaged for the official TeX Live distribution.