# Use Microtype beta from TLContrib with Miktex

Tags: miktex, microtype, repositories, contribute

I would like to test `Microtype 2.5 (b08)` with Lualatex.

I've seen here that `TLContrib` has been cited [as a way to get and install this version](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32508/59030), but I only found solutions to use it as a repository with Tex Live (OK, the name itself tells it already). Is there any way to do it with `Miktex` ? Or have I to do some `texmflocal` trick or even to use Tex Live instead?

Comment: The current version of `microtype` is 2.5a and should be included in the current MiKTeX; the beta version you're mentioning is outdated. I added a comment to the linked question.

Comment: Version 2.5a is listed as current for MiKTeX at http://miktex.org/packages/microtype

Comment: Ok, thanks; I've been confused by the a/alpha – b/beta, and I did not thought that 2.5a could be newer than 2.5 b(eta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of `microtype` is 2.5a (released 2013/05/23) and this is the version available both with TeX Live 2014 and MiKTeX 2.9 (see http://miktex.org/packages/microtype).

The numbering system might be confusing, but 2.5a is a maintenance release after 2.5, which supersedes 2.5beta.